# How do visa issues factor into industry vs postdoc decision in United States?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, industry, visa

I am planning to graduate this fall with a PhD in Mechanical Engineering (Robotics) from UT Austin and is in the process of making a decision to choose between industry and academia as a career choice. I have some questions regarding the same:

I have a job offer from Mathworks and potential post-doc positions from two professors at UT Austin and one at Rice University. It is difficult for me to decide between an industry position and a post-doc in academia. I like publishing papers and have 5 published and 3 under review journal publications, 14 conference papers and 2 pending patents.

If I decide to join Mathworks and later found that academia is a better fit for me. How easy or difficult it is to move out of an industry position back into academia (professor or post-doc position) after a few years considering that the company would file an H1B or green card for me?

What are the long term implications of joining industry as far as staying in US is concerned? I understand that applying for green card is a lengthy process and it is relatively easier through the academic route. Is the industry route too risky and the academic route much safer considering that I am an Indian citizen?

Any advice would be highly valuable for me to make an informed decision.

Comment: Your first list item wasn't actually a question. Anyways, we ask for [one question per post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1204/11365) on this site. So I retitled your question to focus on the second and third items, which are both about visa issues.

Comment: If you have good scholarly work, even if you join the industry, you might be eligible to apply for GC through National Interest Waiver (NIW) or maybe even through EB1. You don't have to be in Academia to apply using these options. I know many of my colleagues (with PhDs and work in industry) who applied via NIW. i would suggest you contact an immigration lawyer to get the most recent information.

Comment: For positions in industry, there is a national quota on the number of H-1B visas that can be issued in each year.  For positions at non-profit higher education institutions, there is no such quota.  Note that if you change positions while on an H-1B visa, your new employer would have to sponsor you for a new visa.